# Python curvefitting with accuracy to find the minimum

Tags: python, python-3.x, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I've had some trouble fitting a curve to the attached data points. First I tried polynomials with different degrees using numpy.polyfit. However it didn't yield results accurate enough to find the minimum of the curve evaluating the derivative of the polynomial. So I tried different solutions like curve fitting in scipy.optimize for a parabola and a gaussian. But it was basically unable to fit a curve and resulted in a covariance matrix of Inf values.

Any insight how I might be able to proceed ?

Thanks in advance,
[image]

Comment: To find an analytic minimum it should be easier to more accurately fit only the data near the data minimum, for example only the data in the range of x > 2.72 and x < 2.76. Visually it appears that a lower-order polynomial should work well for this data range. This could be automated if necessary by using only x +/- 0.02 or 0.03 of the data point with the minimum y value.

Comment: Thanks, in the end I ended up using double gaussian with a slope to find a better estimation of the minimum.